# What are the Maxwell equations of motion in retarded Bondi coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, maxwell-equations, asymptotics

I'm reading a paper about asymptotic symmetries at null infinity in electrodynamics. There, they had the following calculation:
The Maxwell equations $\nabla^{\nu} F_{\mu\nu} = J_{\nu}$ written in retarded Bondi coordinates are

$J_u = (\partial_u - \partial_r) F_{ru} - \frac{2}{r} F_{ru} - \frac{1}{r^2} \gamma^{AB} D_A F_{Bu}$

$J_r = \partial_r F_{ur} + \frac{2}{r} F_{ur} \frac{1}{r^2} - \gamma^{AB} D_A F_{Br}$

$J_C = (\partial_u - \partial_r) F_{rC} + \partial_r F_{uC}+  \frac{1}{r^2} - \gamma^{AB} D_A F_{BC}$

with $\gamma^{AB}$ as the components of the metric of $S^2$. The metric in retarded Bondi coordinates is $ds^2 = du^2 + 2dudr - r^2 \gamma_{AB} d\theta^A d\theta^B$ and $u=t-r$.

I'm in particular confused about the u and r components of the divergence. I don't get to the expression above.